# Printing custom HTML objects asis in Rmd chunks - why does x fail but print(x) work?

Tags: r-markdown

I have defined a custom class and am trying to get it printed properly in RMarkdown - I have managed it for knitting with a custom knit_print method, but fail to get it done in interactive mode.

A very simplified print method is the following - why does x show nothing, while print(x) works, and both lines call the custom print method?

```
library(knitr)
print.myhtml <- function(x) {
   asis_output(x)
}

x <- "<b>Hi there!</b> How are you?"
class(x) <- "myhtml"

x
print(x)
```

It might be related to the [issue that asis_output() only works at the top-level](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1137),  but I am not sure why implicit and explicit printing would work at different levels - and more importantly, how I could resolve this.

Comment: interactive mode is powered by the RStudio IDE and currently knit_print method is not supported in the IDE notebook mode : https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1626

Comment: Thanks to @cderv, I managed to resolve this using htmltools - details here: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/2009